# Who wrote the passage on the Poneglyph at Skypiea?

Tags: one-piece

In chapter 507 the Straw Hat crew meets Rayleigh for the first time. It was then that Robin asked whether Roger was able to understand the ancient language used on the poneglyphs, because at Skypiea she had come across a poneglyph with a passage written on it, supposedly signed by Roger. Yet Rayleigh said that they were merely pirates and that Roger could not match the intellect of those of Ohara. So then in the end, who did write the passage?

> I have come here, and will lead this passage to the very end. - Pirate Gol D. Roger

[image: enter image description here!]
[image: enter image description here!]
[image: enter image description here!]

Comment: I am sorry but this is not a question, because Rayleigh says that they were mere pirates they didn't have anyone from Ohara. Do you remember, in Fishman Arc (not Arlong) that the Sea Kings told each other that Luffy resembles to another pirate that could hear them?? This is exactly the same situation, he could "hear" the language and write something because of this hearing. I think this will be explained further in future arcs.

Comment: @pap So your answer would be that Roger wrote it himself? Although this doesn't explain how he was able to write it correctly though. Imagine if you would be able to hear someone speak Japanese, would you be able to correctly write down what was said without having learned the language?

Comment: That means you don't understand what I wrote. First of all it's fiction not reality don't mix them up, it's not like learning another language. Let me explain you a little more, what happened to Rogers was that when he touched or not, he could be able not to understand the language but to hear something which we dont know yet, and with that he was able to hear what he wanted to write down. When he passed from Fishman Island and heard the Sea Kings it was about the same, he could understand their language and as far as we know only specific fishmen were able to communicate with Sea Kings.

Comment: @pap I understand that he might be able to hear and understand the language, but does hearing and understanding a language make you able to write in it?

Comment: I am not 100% sure that this happened, but I think in near future we will find out!

Answer (score 5):

It seems that we finally know. Oda revealed in chapter 818 that...

> ...it was most likely Lord Kouzuki Oden that wrote down that passage. The Poneglyph were created by the Kouzuki clan and it was confirmed that Lord Oden was able to read the language and write on the stones.
>
>  [image]
>
>  Later it was revealed that he himself had travelled with the former Pirate King, Roger. So chances are that he travelled along with Roger to Skypiea and wrote that additional paragraph.
>
>  [image]

Answer (score 1):

This is finally confirmed in the last page of Chapter 966

> Kozuki Oden is the one that read the poneglyph and write a note on the bell [image: Oden carving the skypiea's bell]

Answer (score -2):

Just like Luffy is stupid and can't understand Poneglyphs, Roger would've have been no good but he might have had a nakama like Robin, probably from Ohara, who may not only be able to read Poneglyphs but also might have a mastery in Poneglyph writing. Seeing Rayleigh mentioning about the Ohara tragedy, makes me think that that Nakama from Ohara was probably separated from others after Roger and with the end of Ohara, Rayleigh would've realised that he even lost another Nakama or maybe Rayleigh just have known the background of Robin (I can't declare for sure). That thing about Rayleigh saying "ability to hear" things is too inexplainary and not adequate to jump to any sort of conclusions but I gues Oda is probably preparing for a new ability for future like he did with Haki. That thing about **Ability to Hear** is similar to what Zoro had experienced during the Alabasta Arc while fighting Mr. 1. He was able to feel/hear the steel, rock, leaves, etc. But I still can't relate it to this Rayleigh's proposed **Hearing Abiltiy** theory. So I guess it would've been the work of a scholarly Roger Nakama like Robin.

Comment: "Ability to hear" is not referring to Zoro listening to rocks, leaves. Thats referring his haki awakening. This refers to Luffy being able to listen to sea kings in the Fishman Island arc. And sea kings also mention that this is the second human to be able to understand them.